# Is there a way to reference material design specs in my app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I'm going to have lots of different colours in my app, using the [Material Design specs for colour](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html).

This means I will need to copy and paste the hex code for the colour from the website into my XML file (`colours.xml`), but doing this for a lot of colours is going to be tedious.

Similarly, I want to be able to use the [keyline and spacing values from the spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing) in my app, but not have to add these in manually to my `dimens.xml`.

Is there some sort of way I can reference colours/dimensions/etc from the material design spec, without having to add the values I want manually into my XML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library called **MaterialDesignUtils** which can help you reference values as you want (have a look at it [on GitHub](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/MaterialDesignUtils)).

To use it, you need to add the following into your module's `build.gradle` script:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.farbod.mdutils:mdutils:+'
}
```

Now, instead of having to look up the hex value into your `colours.xml` (or somewhere else - e.g. XML layout), you can reference the material design colours in the following format:

```
@color/mdu_COLOUR_VARIANT
```

where `COLOUR` is the name of the colour group from the spec (e.g. red, pink, purple, deep purple, etc.), and `VARIANT` is the type of that colour (e.g. 50, 100, 200, ..., a700).

So you can use this value in your `colours.xml` like this, for example:

```
<resources>
    <color name="theme_primary">@color/mdu_red_500</color>
</resources>
```

You can reference dimensions in the same way (e.g. `@dimen/`).

However, if you already have some colours in your `colours.xml` file that you want to convert to references to the library (e.g. converting...

```
<resources>
    <color name="theme_primary">#F44336</color>
</resources>
```

...to something more like the previous example), I would look at the **mdu-file-converter** program ([also on GitHub](https://github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/mdu-file-converter)).

I develop both of these tools, so if you encounter a problem, let me know via an issue on GitHub. Hope this solved your problem.